# how can i get code coverage with clang++ 13.0.1 on mac?

Tags: code-coverage, clang++

I am trying to create a code coverage report for an executable compiled with clang++ 13.0.1 on Mac. The clang++ and support tools come from the 13.0.1 release binary download on the LLVM Project's github site. Running `clang++ --version` verifies that it is version 13.0.1.

The `test` object files and executable are compiled and linked using the "-fprofile-instr-generate -fcoverage-mapping" flags. Running the test generates a .profraw file, as expected:

```sh
LLVM_PROFILE_FILE="code-%6m.profraw" test

file code-18395704024281647848_0.profraw
code-18395704024281647848_0.profraw: LLVM raw profile data, version 5
```

Unfortunately, when i try to convert the .profraw file to .profdata format for use by llvm-cov, llvm-profdata complains:

```sh
llvm-profdata merge code-18395704024281647848_0.profraw -o out.profdata
warning: code-18395704024281647848_0.profraw: unsupported instrumentation profile format version
```

Perhaps i have missed something which is easily corrected or there is a better/more common approach for determining code coverage. Any help appreciated!

Comment: I think the steps described above are consistent with the [current clang documentation for source-based code coverage](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/SourceBasedCodeCoverage.html).

Comment: Minimal [test project using the latest 13.0.1 binary release for mac](https://github.com/bobpretzel/code_coverage)

Comment: If i run the *minimal test project* on Ubuntu 20 using the 13.0.1 binaries it works. On Ubuntu, the compiled binary is producing profraw version 7 format (as opposed to version 5 on the mac). Perhaps the mac binaries, for some reason, are producing a profraw which is incompatible with the bundled llvm coverage tools?

Comment: 14.0.0, just released, has the same issue. [LLVM issue created](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/54571).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
Adding `xcrun` before the command solves this problem。

```
xcrun llvm-profdata merge -sparse default.profraw -o default.profdata
xcrun llvm-cov show ./sum_up -instr-profile=default.profdata
```